# How to Remove Annoying Magazine/Book Entries from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

Whenever I try to search the Ubuntu Software Center for apps, my results list is flooded with magazine and book entries. Is it possible to remove these annoying entries?

Thanks!